# How to center the title and an image in streamlit?

Tags: python, css, streamlit

I've already tried the command below for the title and I couldn't. For the image, I just managed to center it by increasing the size so that it fills the entire page. Are there any arguments to `st.title()` and `st.image` that allow me to center them?

```
title_alignment=
"""
<style>
#the-title {
  text-align: center
}
</style>
"""
st.markdown(title_alignment, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Answer (score 18):

To center a text you can either use markdown like this:

```
#A streamlit app with two centered texts with different seizes
import streamlit as st

st.markdown("<h1 style='text-align: center; color: grey;'>Big headline</h1>", unsafe_allow_html=True)

st.markdown("<h2 style='text-align: center; color: black;'>Smaller headline in black </h2>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

Or you can use streamlit's column keyword like this:

```
import streamlit as st

col1, col2, col3 = st.columns(3)

with col1:
    st.write(' ')

with col2:
    st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/dog.jpg")

with col3:
    st.write(' ')
```

[image]

This creates containers where you can add text and images. This way you are able to center images.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another approach, simplifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70941664/6243352) a bit and avoiding HTML:

```py
import streamlit as st  # 1.18.1

with st.columns(3)[1]:
     st.header("hello world")
     st.image("https://picsum.photos/200/200")
```

Or if you're just rendering one item:

```py
st.columns(3)[1].header("hello world")
```

If you want to center the text within the column, though, it seems HTML is the only way. If you don't mind globally centering all `<h2>`s, you can use:

```py
style = "<style>h2 {text-align: center;}</style>"
st.markdown(style, unsafe_allow_html=True)
st.columns(3)[1].header("hello world")
```

See also [Center Streamlit Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75477141/6243352).

Answer (score 3):

Using columns to align the image in the center won't work all the time. A more concrete option would be to use markdown to show the image.

But first the image has to be converted to Base64. Below is the solution to do so for a png image.

```
# Solution provided by dataprofessor (https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/image-in-markdown/13274/10) modified by mze3e to center the image
# img_to_bytes and img_to_html inspired from https://pmbaumgartner.github.io/streamlitopedia/sizing-and-images.html

import base64
from pathlib import Path

def img_to_bytes(img_path):
    img_bytes = Path(img_path).read_bytes()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(img_bytes).decode()
    return encoded
def img_to_html(img_path):
    img_html = "<img src='data:image/png;base64,{}' class='img-fluid'>".format(
      img_to_bytes(img_path)
    )
    return img_html

st.markdown(<p style='text-align: center; color: grey;'>"+img_to_html('image.png')+"</p>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```